# How to find some values in array returned by mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

I have voting system in my site and i want to check that user has upvoted,downvoted or not.
To reduce the no. of queries i selected complete table containing id equals to user id from voting table
table schema for vote table is [image: Vote table]
table schema for answer table is [image: answer table]

```
$query=SELECT answer_id,user_id,vote FROM vote WHERE user_id='{$_SESSION["id"]}'
$result1=mysql_query($query);
$array=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
```

now when i fetch the answers of question i want to check that if this user has voted or not
if answer_id has found in this array than than i want to find the value of vote ?

code is

```
$query1="SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='{$question_id}'";//$question_id is id of question
$result=mysql_query($query1);
if($result){
    While ($row=mysql_fetch_arrar($result)){
        if(in_array($row["id"],$array){
            echo $array["vote"];
        }
    }
}
```

I am confused how to fetch two array together...?This query only works for first value because i am not using while loop in $array,Can anybody help me..?

Comment: I think you can LEFT JOIN two queries on the common field (here it may be answer_id) and add where condition for that answer_id.

Comment: This might be easier to answer if we could see the schema for those two tables

Comment: If `$_SESSION["id"]` and/or `$question_id` are numerical values, you **MUST** put them as `question_id=$question_id` in your query with no single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in one query to determine if a user has voted for an answer. There is no need for a preliminary query to get user votes, or an array comparison inside the fetch loop.

Use a `LEFT JOIN` against a subquery on `votes` and supply the userid in its `WHERE` clause. If the value of `uservotes.vote` is NULL, the user has *not* voted for this answer. Otherwise, `uservotes.vote` will contain the user's vote.

```
SELECT
  answers.*,
  uservotes.vote
FROM 
  answers 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT answer_id, vote FROM votes WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION["id"]}'
  ) uservotes ON answers.id = uservotes.answer_id
WHERE answers.question_id = {$question_id}
```

Comment: i have given my database schema would you plz tell me exact values....I am not so familiar with LEFT JOIN ??

Comment: @Lokesh I don't know what more you would need. I have given you the complete query, the only one needed. Test it out and verify it gives results